# Updating appointment recipient's response status

Tags: outlook-addin

I am developing an Outlook 2010 add in using VS 2010, and c#

In that i want to modify appointment recipient's meeting status programmatically. I can read it from the property 'appointmentitem.Recipients[1].MeetingResponseStatus'. But it is a read only property. Is there any way to update this property. Manually it is possible to update (set accepted,Declined etc) this property through 'Tracking' tab of the appointment form ribbon

Since it is possible to edit the response manually i think it can be done programmatically also?

Any Help??

Thanking you in advance